# Split payment between Stripe and Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, stripe-payments

I'm working on a checkout system that has the following requirements:
Stephen buys product and pays using Paypal. Product is $10, Jim gets $7 and Omar gets $3. Jim is paid via Paypal and Omar is paid via Stripe.

I'm aware of both Paypal chained payments and Stripe Connect, and I'm using both APIs in our application already. I'm just not sure how to take a payment made with Paypal and send partial funds to a Managed Stripe account.

Another potential workflow is to accept a users payment via credit card, then make a partial payment to Jim using Paypal and a partial payment to Omar using Stripe.

Are either of these possible?

Comment: There's no way to send funds to a managed account in Stripe if you haven't take the payment with Stripe originally. The other way around would work if you pay Jim using your own funds on Paypal after Stripe sends you the funds in your bank account.